# What is the difference in char *p and const char * p in c++?

Tags: c++

```
class str
{
    char *p;
    public:
       string(const char *s);
}
```

I am confused about the difference between these two declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`const char *` is a pointer to a const char, you cant change the value being pointed to, but you can change the pointer

`char * const` is a constant pointer to a char, [behaving like a reference type] you can change the value pointed to but you cant change the pointer.

`const char * const` is a constant pointer to a constant char, [both are constants]